# Firebase Services as library module

Tags: android, firebase, multi-module, android-multi-module

Is there a way to use Firebase services in a library/module? I am planning of creating a module for Firebase only, I know that Firebase services need `FirebaseApp` instance to identify the app client but I wonder if there is a possibility of creating a module that consist of Firebase product only which then can be consume in app level

Comment: Why this shouldn't be possible? I'd rather think it would only complicate everything for no apparent reason. Better build a Google product flavor and you'd have it all in one source-set.

Comment: @MartinZeitler How about using it as git submodule? So whenever you need to update certain part of the code you don't need to copy paste it, just pull the submodule.

Answer (score 0):

I already managed to do this, the idea is Firebase SDK is in a submodule which contains your common use case, extension function, etc that you might want to reuse like a template whenever you are working on a new project that has Firebase services. The app module will still be responsible for initializing your Firebase services in Application class like this.

`FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)`